# CMake for Swift alternative to target_compile_definitions

Tags: swift, unit-testing, cmake

The project I am working on uses CMake to build and I'm a little new to CMake. I am trying to setup a unit test target in the project to test some SWIFT code. The project contains several examples of setting up unit test in ObjC but none with SWIFT which means it's up to me to figure it out. The way the testing code is set up if there is any UT specific code in the code base it is contained inside a pair of `#ifdef SOME_DEFINE #endif`. That way we can define things that are strictly for testing purposes but won't compile into the finished product.

Now comes the part I'm having issues with. SWIFT doesn't have `#define` and uses global constants instead. Consequently I can't use `target_compile_definitions` to create a define that I can use to tell the compiler not to compile a section of code. When I try to use `target_compile_definitions` I get a compile error saying `<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file 'SOME_DEFINE' (No such file or directory)`. What is a good work around for this?

**EDIT:**

**CMake**

```
target_compile_definitions(Some_SWIFT_Unit_Tests
    PRIVATE
        -DSOME_DEFINE=1
)
```

**ObjC**

```
#ifdef SOME_DEFINE
// Some UT specific code goes here
#endif
```

Comment: Instead of *describing* the code **show** it (add to the question post). See also [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev does that help?

Comment: Remove the `-D`.

Comment: @KamilCuk no luck.

Comment: Please compile with verbose (`cmake --build ... --verbose` or `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` etc.) and inspect the compilation command.